# Yours Lovingly and Yours Loving

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives, possessives, grammaticality-in-context

Can an informal Letter end as:

1) Yours Loving,
John

OR

2) Yours Lovingly,
John

OR

3) Your Loving Son,
John

I guess the 2nd and the 3rd ones are okay; I'm not sure about the 1st one, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can end an informal letter any way you like as this is a matter of preference and possibly etiquette rather than grammar.

However, **Yours Loving** is unusual and somewhat puzzling. So unless you want to mystify the recipient, it's best avoided.

Also, in all three examples, the word **loving** would usually be in lower case rather than with a capital **L**. And your name would be on the line below.

Apart from that, examples 2 & 3 seem fine, assuming that your love for the recipient is what you especially want to convey.

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the first two versions, the most *common* way of ending a letter with the words you picked would be:

> Lovingly yours, John.

Typically, an adjective comes before **yours**.

---

The last version is fine. Although, in it and the others, only the first word and any proper nouns should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that "Yours Loving" sounds very odd (but that if it's informal you can sign off however you like). However they don't explain the why.

Valedictions such as "Lovingly yours", "Sincerely yours", etc. are all variations on shortening the phrase "I am yours".

"Am" is a verb and so it has to be modified by an adverb: "I am lovingly yours", "I am sincerely yours" etc.

If someone said, "I am loving yours," I would respond, "You are loving my what?" :)

Consider the responses to this very similar question: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/166374/314427

Comment: *Lovingly* here is not modifying *am*. It is like *I am happy*, where *happy* is an *adjective* modifying the subject, not an adverb modifying the verb. In *I am lovingly yours*, *lovingly* is not modifying the verb *am*. Depending on how you view it, it is either modifying the subject (noun) "I" or pronoun "yours". In either case, it is an adjective. In *I am loving yours*, *am* is a helper verb and *loving* is the main verb. *Lovingly* is not a verb at all and shouldn't be used analogously.

Comment: "am is a helper verb and loving is the main verb." Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't spend much time on it because it was more of an aside.
"Lovingly is not a verb at all." True, but I'm not sure what it has to do with anything I said.
"lovingly is not modifying the verb am … it is either modifying the subject (noun) 'I' or pronoun 'yours'." 
I can't say I'm convinced by this. Do you have an argument or source for it? "Loving" can be an adjective, "lovingly" is the adverb form. Why would it be modifying a noun in this case? What would it even mean for 'I' or 'yours' to be 'lovingly'?

Comment: Compare *I am yours* to *I am* ***lovingly*** *yours*, *I am* ***gratefully*** *yours*, *I am* ***very much*** *yours*, or *I am yours* ***without a doubt***. Or look at *I am rich* and *I am* ***happily*** *rich*.

Comment: It was through comparison with exactly those kinds of variation that convinced me that the adverb was modifying **am** in the first place. In particular, "I am **truly** yours" or "I am yours **without a doubt**" could also be conveyed simply by emphasising the *am*, "I **am** yours".

In "I am **happily** rich” the happily is doing its normal work by modifying the *adjective* rich. You can see this by placing “happily rich” in a different position, e.g. “a happily rich man”. You can’t do this with “happily yours”.